# Komodo-Edit select and then copy with mouse not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, komodoedit

I'm using Komodo-edit on Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome fallback metacity window manager. Since upgrade from Ubuntu 13.10, select and copy using the mouse do not work. I can select the word or phrase with the left mouse but as soon as a I use right mouse click to copy or find, etc., the selection goes away. This forces me to select with mouse and then use keyboard shortcuts to complete the operation. Very inconvenient. I have since moved to Sublime Text but would prefer to use Komodo. Can anyone advise how to get mouse control working again? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to Unity and found that the mouse worked as expected. I have never adjusted to unity , but found a link that allowed me customize it to work more acceptably by installing cairo dock. See here http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/tweak-ubuntu-unity-get-a-dock-style-launcher-and-unity-dash/